# MySQL data not fully being shown in html table. Data gets cut off and leaves half the field not the full

Tags: php, html-table

Here's the Code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM situations");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Case#</th>
<th>Cop(s)</th>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Vehicle/Person</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Division(s)</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<form action=situations.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Case#'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=cop value=" . $row['Cops']. " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=sector value=". $row['Code'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=vehicle value=" . $row['Vehicle'] ." </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=location value="  .$row['Location'].  " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=division value=" .$row['Division'].  " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" .$row['Case #'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update_situations value=Update" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I have it so I can update it  but my data is not fully shown. EX: I would have "Dukes Blvd" in Location and it would only show "Dukes" Please Help! and I am  newb to PHP, MySQL.

Comment: not sure anyone would agree with me, but I like to end the PHP, write the HTML then continue the PHP again:  while(){ ?> <!--HTML --> <?PHP } ?>  -  It just makes it easier to read and you don't have to worry about quotes.  Then you can echo the php variables with <?= $variable ?>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<form action="situations.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Case#']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cop" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Cops'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sector" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Code'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="vehicle" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Vehicle'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Location'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="division" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Division'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Case #'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="update_situations" value="Update"></td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: ^^ +1 @Phillip --  Or at the very least `stripslashes()`/`addslashes()`

Comment: I took a look at the example code that i got from a video tutorial and its the same way i have it with just my info... So i think it might be MySQL error or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with ntgCleaner about ending PHP although some times its extra work. If you always use the same rules for quotes its not to big a problem plus after a while you recognize the syntax error right off or it is usually the first thing I look for when I get one. I always start with a single quote followed by a double quote inside the html portions.

echo 'some code "quoted code" more code'.$variable;

You can also use a backslash to id the quote \' to separate it from an error state.

Comment: Since this isn't directly answering the question, it should probably be a comment on the question, and not an answer.

Comment: OK will directly answer "Put the correct sequence of quotes in your code." Like echo'<td><input type="text" name="cop" value="'.$row['Cops'].'"></td>';

Comment: It give me a Syntax error in Dreamweaver when i tried the sequence thing.